# Classes with multiple attribute levels [Beginner]

Tags: python, class, attributes

Does python have a similar functionality with its data structure similar to what can be seen in MATLAB?

For example, being able to call a class similar to what follows:

```
variable = Class(inputs)
```

would allow to call *variable* with multiple attributes (not sure if attributes is the correct terminology here).

```
variable.attribute1.attribute2
```

In other words, defining a Class would provide the functionality of these multiple attributes.  I am only seeking documentation if such functionality exists.

I'll add a little example because my question is quite vague.
So, I'll define a class that assigns data sets to a variable.

```
class Properties(object):

    def __init__(self, data_set1, data_set2):
        self.Data1 = data_set1
        self.Data2 = data_set2
```

Now, I'll define a variable.

```
variable = Properties([1, 2, 3, 7], [3, 9, 2, 8])
```

Obviously now I can call variable with its individual data sets as:

```
variable.Data1
variable.Data2
```

What I desire is to have another Class that will be able to then define Statistical properties of the sets, such as:

```
variable.Data1.Maximum
variable.Data1.Minimum
variable.Data2.StandardDev
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but the answer is yes. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Attribute(object):
    pass

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute1 = Attribute()

variable = MyClass()
variable.attribute1.attribute2 = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

A class is an object that has attributes (python objects... in python, everything is an object) and behavior (functions).

When you initialize a class with `Class(inputs)` it actually runs that classes constructor, which can set up some or all of the resulting objects attributes, such as variable.attribute1

An attribute can be any data type... numbers, strings, or even other classes.  This means that attribute1 could be an object of Class2, which has it's OWN attribute named attribute2 (which could be an object of any type, including another class, even an object of type Class or Class2 if you wanted to get crazy lol).

So, the TL;DR ... yes.